# Git merge a remote into a local branch

Tags: git, git-merge

I have made a local branch called develop and have made some changes to it. However I now want to merge another developers changes to remotes/devteam/master into my develop local branch.

How best do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already have a remote defined for *devteam*:

```
git fetch --all
git checkout develop
git merge devteam/master
```